# Use slurm JobID as input?

Tags: slurm, sbatch

Is it possible to use the JobID as an input of the script you are submiting?

I know you can use %j to name the log file with the JobID, but is it possible to do, for example, something similar to

```
sbatch make-dir.sh %j
```

where make-dir.sh is

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $1
```

As it stands now, it will print %j, but I would like it to print the JobID.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the environment variable `$SLURM_JOBID` in the make-dir.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $SLURM_JOBID
```

Comment: Just to add, when a job starts on a compute node, SLURM creates a massive list of environment variables that contain useful information such as the JobID, number of nodes, number of tasks and more. They can be found under OUTPUT ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES in the [sbatch manual](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html)